# How to send an email with multiple attachments

Tags: vbscript

This code is working well as long as every file is there.
What is missing in the code for sending an email even if a file is missing?
I have tried to find a solution but without success.

```
Set fso=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

strSMTP="smtp.telenor.no"
strSubject="Files form me to you"
strSubject="XXXXX"
strSubject="XXXX"
strBody="XXXXXX"
strAttach="File 1.csv"
strAttach1="File 2.csv"
strAttach2="File 3.csv"

If fso.FileExists(strAttach) then
Set iMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set iConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
iConf.Load -1    ' CDO Source Defaults
Set Flds = iConf.Fields
With Flds
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = strSMTP
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
    .Update
End With
With iMsg
    Set .Configuration = iConf
    .To = "XXXX"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .From = "XXXX"
    .Subject = strSubject
    .TextBody = strBody
    .AddAttachment strAttach
    .AddAttachment strAttach1
    .AddAttachment strAttach2
    .Send
End With
Set iMsg = Nothing
Set iConf = Nothing
Else
MsgBox "The specified attachment does not exist"
End if
```

Comment: Only the existence of `strAttach` is checked. Your code doesn't check `strAttach2` and `strAttach3`.

Comment: this code could be a lot cleaner if you placed the files in an array, checking their existence and added them as attachments in a `For` statement. (principle: [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following uses an ArrayList to hold your attachments and adds them to the message one by one, checking if the file exists first:

```
Dim iCounter
Dim sAttachment
Dim objAttachments

Set objAttachments = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

objAttachments.Add "File 1.csv"
objAttachments.Add "File 2.csv"
objAttachments.Add "File 3.csv"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

strSMTP = "smtp.telenor.no"
strSubject = "Files form me to you"
strSubject = "XXXXX"
strSubject = "XXXX"
strBody = "XXXXXX"

' Create message and configuration
Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set objConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

objConf.Load -1    ' CDO Source Defaults
Set objFields = objConf.Fields

With objFields
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = strSMTP
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
    .Update
End With

' Initalize message
With objMessage
    Set .Configuration = objConf
    .To = "XXXX"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .From = "XXXX"
    .Subject = strSubject
    .TextBody = strBody
End With

' Add attachments
For iCounter = 1 To objAttachments.Count
    sAttachment = objAttachments.Item(iCounter - 1)
    If objFSO.FileExists(sAttachment) Then objMessage.AddAttachment sAttachment
Next

' Send Message
objMessage.Send
```

Comment: Great! Please mark the answer as accepted using the gray checkmark to the left of the answer when you get a chance!

Comment: Why did you choose an arraylist over a simple array? Just out of curiousity.

Comment: Reason I ask is because it introduces a dependency on .Net.

Comment: @ArnovanBoven I was trying to mimic how a VB6 Collection object works. A Dictionary could've worked just as well.

Comment: Fair enough. @Frank be aware that the accepted answer requires .Net. It *can* be done more natively in VBS with either an `Array` or `Dictionary`. The provided answer *is* more convenient, granted.